# can I add extra flags to meson ```compiles``` test?

Tags: avx2, meson-build

I want to use the `ret` variable to check, whether my cpu supports avx2:

```
    ret = cc.compiles('''
        #include <immintrin.h>
        int main() {
            __m256i m = _mm256_set1_epi32(17);
            return sizeof(__mm256_srli_epi32(m 8);
        }
        ''')
```

but I need to add somehow the compilation flag `-mavx2`.
Is that possible?
I read that in 2019 it wasn't, but maybe it has changed?

Comment: Even with optimization disabled, that doesn't check for AVX2 availability.  Note that `_mm256_srli_epi32(m, 8)` is inside a `sizeof`, so it never executes.  GCC will even *compile* it with only `-mavx` (https://godbolt.org/z/T3eKz3j3v), not requiring `-mavx2` or `-march=znver1`.  A better version https://godbolt.org/z/q56r769xM avoids that problem, compiling (with `-O0`) to include an AVX2 `vpsrld` instruction.  (Actually since I used `volatile __m256i`, it tests correctly even with `-O3`.)

Comment: You can probably use GNU C `__attribute__((target("avx2")))` for this, if build options are a problem.  Yup, https://godbolt.org/z/fxfPTWGGE shows that works for GCC (and clang/ICC).  You can ifdef it for MSVC, which lets you use intrinsic for extensions that aren't enabled.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/6739)

Answer (score 0):

The badly documented args keyword is what you want:

```
cc.compiles(..., args : [...])
```